# Align content to the right of cell

Tags: bootstrap-4

I'm trying to set some content to the right of a cells.
Here is an example:

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group float-right">
        <a class="btn">BTN 1</a>
        <a class="btn">BTN 2</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Previously I was on bootstrap 2, and I had a pull-right. I saw on the bootstrap 4 documentation pull-right got removed and we had to use pull-right instead. But looks like this is not working at all.

I might not be using it properly. Thanks for your help.

EDIT: Here is a fiddle with what I have: I want to set the Action td to float right: http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/95785/

Comment: try `text-right`

Comment: `text-right` is not working

Comment: Consider adding a Plunker or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

`pull-right` did not work in bootstrap 4 it's replaced by float-right please use this code:

```
<td>
    <div class="btn-group float-right">
        <a class="btn">BTN 1</a>
        <a class="btn">BTN 2</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table border="1" class="w-100">
    <tr>
        <td>
         <div class="btn-group d-inline-block float-right">
           <a class="btn">BTN 1</a>
           <a class="btn">BTN 2</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In your code check with this change

```
<div class="btn-group text-nowrap d-inline-block float-right">
```

Comment: I don't understand because when I applied your change to fiddle it's working...but when I apply to my own page it's not working anymore...

Comment: Can I see a screenshot of your page with the new changes applied?

Comment: 1. For debugginh can you add a new class to div `border`  eg: `<div class="btn-group d-inline-block float-right text-nowrap border">`
2. Can confirm if you are using BS4.0 or above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176124/discussion-between-kiranvj-and-minirock-akeru).